# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datefinder' in Jupyter notebook-- but can be imported in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, datefinder

I am trying to use the module datefinder inside Jupyter Notebook. After activating a virtual environment inside the terminal, I installed this module using the following command: `conda install -c conda-forge datefinder`. When I try to import this module inside Jupyter notebook using `from datefinder import find_dates` I see this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datefinder'

In the terminal (using Python 3.9.6), I can import the module datefinder but not inside the Jupyter Notebook (using Python 3.7.6). After that I also used `pip install datefinder` inside the `Jupyter Notebook` to install `datefinder`. After successfully installing `datefinder`, when I again tried to import this module, I still saw the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datefinder'`. The same problem persisted, I could use the module inside terminal and not inside the notebook.

I faced similar problem when installing opencv using conda and troubleshooted this by adding kernel manually as described in this page https://www.programmersought.com/article/97466914065/ . I have also tried by changing the default kernel to the kernel I created manually and then tried to import this module and still I saw the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Perform the installation on the `jupyter notebook`  as shown below:

```
pip install datefinder
```

[image]

for more go to [Github](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder)

Comment: I used pip to install datefinder before posting this question and still saw the same error.

Comment: @shammun What error does it send during installation?

Comment: It doesn't show any error during the installation. But when I try to import the module after the installation is completed, the ModuleNotFoundError is shown again.

Comment: you may need to restart the `kernel` to use updated packages

Comment: Tried before but doesn't help either.

Comment: `import sys  
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user datefinder` for more read http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/